# Remap CapsLock to Delete on Sierra

Tags: keyboard, macos, keybindings

Hi I've just got my **MacBook Pro 2016** running 10.12.3 and I'm in a bit of a pickle...

I can't seem to find a way to remap my CapsLock to Delete.

I've tried using **Seil**, **Ukelele** and some other software, but non seem to do the job. Seil did't do anything after I've tried using it, and **Ukelele** seems a bit confusing, I just want to remap a single key, not the whole keyboard.

Could anybody recommend a software or method i could do this.
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah found the solution. Currently the best option, by **FAR** is:

## [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/usage/README.md)

Hope somebody else finds this useful as well.

Comment: Specifical steps in Karabiner-Elements: under Simple Modifications, Add Item: From "caps_lock" To "delete_or_backspace".  I also remapped "caps_lock" to "vk_none (disable this key)" to get used to the muscle memory (after I switched to the [Colemak](https://colemak.com/) keyboard layout)

Answer (score 1):

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000039,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000002A}]}'
```

Taken from http://homeowmorphism.com/2017/05/27/Remap-CapsLock-Backspace-Sierra

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the same thing on High Sierra, its now native!  Go to System Preferences ->  keyboard -> keyboard tab: "Modifier keys ..." button.

From there you can choose where it maps to.

Comment: How do you map it to backspace/delete there?

Answer (score 0):

Using hiutil to swap the delete and the caplock key:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000002A,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000039},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000039,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000002A}]}'
```