# How to remap a single key?

Tags: macos, keybindings

I have a broken key on my Mac's keyboard and I need to remap it to some other key, by double press. Temporarily.

It's not a special but an alphabet letter one. I want to remap it this way:

```
"f" (broken) --> "double a"
```

How can one do it? Preferably without any third-party tool.

**update1**

This hasn't worked - double a won't get replaced with f whenever I type "aa" anywhere on my laptop. I want it to replace double a with f on the fly.

[image]

Comment: If any third party tool is accepted, I would suggest [Karabinar-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) or [HammerSpoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap CapsLock to Delete on Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275812/remap-capslock-to-delete-on-sierra)

Comment: There are many existing questions/answers on remapping keys; many refer to 3rd party tools, but also show how to do this with the built in  tool `hidutil`. The linked dupe is just one. Give that a go and update how that works out for you.

Comment: *"This hasn't worked - double a won't get replaced with f whenever I type "aa""* Which app did you try it in ? works for me in say Safari search bar

Comment: @anki why do you need the name of an app? there're millions of them

Comment: If you are using Word or another non-Apple app, you may need to set the text replacement in their own preferences, as some do not use Apple stuff for this (or for spell check, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If the broken key is one of the characters, not function, or modifier keys:

Set up a text replacement for say `ZZ` -> `A` (broken key).

System preferences > Keyboard > Text.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-keyboard-text-preferences-on-mac-mh27071/10.14/mac/10.14.6

Word and other non-Apple apps can have their own text-replacement preferences that would have have to be set.

A long-winded way is to set up a "Service" or a Script Editor's "Script" to keystroke the key you need.

- [How do I automate a key press in AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript/36947#36947)

Comment: `System preferences > Keyboard > Text.` --> and?

Comment: @kosmosu05 Add a text replacement .. See edited answer

Comment: This will only work in  Cocoa based apps. For instance, it will work in Pages, but not in  Word.

Comment: @Allan But Word has its own settings for this, no problem to do it there.